# Is there a way to store variables without changing them into strings?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, variables

I have an array in my code that changes value through a function.

```
var arr = [];

function arrfunction() {
arr.push(1);
}
```

I then change my HTML page to a different one using:

```
windows.location.replace("page2.html");
```

Since I change pages, my variable resets. I have tried to use sessionStorage to store arr, but I have to use JSON.stringify() to convert it into a string. The issue is, I need arr to remain as an array for later use.

Is there a way I can store my variable and also keep it as an array?

Comment: So convert it a string and convert it back to an array with JSON methods.

Answer (score 2):

Cant you just use `JSON.parse()` to turn the string back into a normal array and use sessionStorage?

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly how it works.

store:

```
const arr = [1];
sessionStorage.setItem("arr",JSON.stringify(arr)); // or localStorage
```

retrieve on other page:

```
const arr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arr")); // or localStorage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse to convert the stringify arr back to array.

For your reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse